# Ionic 5 App Image download for external URL, Need a working Code repository

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4, ionic-native, ionic5

I was trying in different ways but nothing worked so far. Need an ionic 5 Angular app code that runs in Android and downloads an image from any of the external URLs.

Thanks in advance